# Accessing Redux Store from routes set up via React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

I would like to make use of react-router's `onEnter` handler in order to prompt users to authenticate when entering a restricted route.

So far my `routes.js` file looks something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

export default (
    <Route   path="/"         component={App}>
      <IndexRoute             component={Landing} />
      <Route path="learn"     component={Learn} />
      <Route path="about"     component={About} />
      <Route path="downloads" component={Downloads} onEnter={requireAuth} />
    </Route>
)
```

Ideally, I'd like my `requireAuth` function to be a redux action that has access to the store and current state, that works like this: `store.dispatch(requireAuth())`.

Unfortunately I don't have access to the store in this file. I don't think I can use really use [`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) in this case to access the relevant actions that I want. I also can't just `import store` from the file where the store is created, as this is undefined when the app first loads.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to pass your store to a function that returns your routes (rather than return your routes directly). This way you can access the store in `onEnter` and other react router methods.

So for your routes:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

export const getRoutes = (store) => (
  const authRequired = (nextState, replaceState) => {
    // Now you can access the store object here.
    const state = store.getState();

    if (!state.user.isAuthenticated) {
      // Not authenticated, redirect to login.
      replaceState({ nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }, '/login');
    }
  };

  return (
    <Route   path="/"         component={App}>
      <IndexRoute             component={Landing} />
      <Route path="learn"     component={Learn} />
      <Route path="about"     component={About} />
      <Route path="downloads" component={Downloads} onEnter={authRequired} />
    </Route>
  );
)
```

Then update your main component to call the `getRoutes` function, passing in the store:

```
<Provider store={ store }>
  <Router history={ history }>
    { getRoutes(store) }
  </Router>
</Provider>
```

As for dispatching an action from `requireAuth`, you could write your function like this:

```
const authRequired = (nextState, replaceState, callback) => {
  store.dispatch(requireAuth())  // Assume this action returns a promise
    .then(() => {
      const state = store.getState();

      if (!state.user.isAuthenticated) {
        // Not authenticated, redirect to login.
        replaceState({ nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }, '/login');
      }

      // All ok
      callback();
    });
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thats a great example. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: TY some much, this approach is really easy tom implement, but i need ask, is there any draw back with this?

Comment: react-router had a minor change,
redirecting from an onEnter hook now also uses a location descriptor.

see https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#link-to-onenter-and-isactive-use-location-descriptors

Answer (score 13):

If you want that you could write route.js like this:

```
var requireAuth = (store, nextState, replace) => {
  console.log("store: ", store);
  //now you have access to the store in the onEnter hook!
}

export default (store) => {
  return (
      <Route path="/"           component={App}>
        <IndexRoute             component={Landing} />
        <Route path="learn"     component={Learn} />
        <Route path="about"     component={About} />
        <Route path="downloads" component={Downloads} onEnter={requireAuth.bind(this, store)} />
      </Route>
    );
);
```

I've setup an example which you could play with in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/alexchiri/pen/yOevGZ/).

Not sure if triggering an action in order to handle the auth is a good idea. Personally I prefer handling auth in **a different way**:

Instead of using an `onEnter` hook, I use a wrapping function. I want the admin section of my blog protected, therefore I wrapped the `AdminContainer` component in the routes with a function, `requireAuthentication`, see below.

```
export default (store, history) => {
        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                <Route path="/" component={App}>
                    { /* Home (main) route */ }
                    <IndexRoute component={HomeContainer}/>
                    <Route path="post/:slug" component={PostPage}/>
                    { /* <Route path="*" component={NotFound} status={404} /> */ }
                </Route>

                <Route path="/admin" component={requireAuthentication(AdminContainer)}>
                    <IndexRoute component={PostList}/>
                    <Route path=":slug/edit" component={PostEditor}/>
                    <Route path="add" component={PostEditor}/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
            </Router>
        );
    };
```

`requireAuthentication` is a function that

- if the user is authenticated, renders the wrapped component,
- otherwise redirects to `Login`

You can see it below:

```
export default function requireAuthentication(Component) {
    class AuthenticatedComponent extends React.Component {

        componentWillMount () {
            this.checkAuth();
        }

        componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
            this.checkAuth();
        }

        checkAuth () {
            if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
                let redirectAfterLogin = this.props.location.pathname;
                this.context.router.replace({pathname: '/login', state: {redirectAfterLogin: redirectAfterLogin}});
            }
        }

        render () {
            return (
                <div>
                    {this.props.isAuthenticated === true
                        ? <Component {...this.props}/>
                        : null
                    }
                </div>
            )

        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
        isAuthenticated: state.blog.get('isAuthenticated')
    });

    AuthenticatedComponent.contextTypes = {
        router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    return connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthenticatedComponent);
}
```

Also, `requireAuthentication` will protect all routes under `/admin`. And you can reuse it wherever you like.

Comment: Seems like AuthenticatedComponent is the usage of visual React component that for non-visual route auth checking purposes. Don't you thinks all those componentWillMount isn't about the route auth checking at all?

Comment: I agree @alex_1948511, it's a hack. But then again, very few things are well defined in the JS world (or maybe it's just my view as a n00b in JS programming). I'm open to any suggestions on how to do this better in React. I haven't looked into this in the past months, since I found this approach somewhere on the Internet I haven't really looked further. :-)

Comment: I may add, in Router v4, you cannot nest Router Tags. This will throw an error

Answer (score 4):

Lots have changed over the time. `onEnter` no longer exists on `react-router-4`

The following is from my real project for your reference

```js
export const getRoutes = (store) => {
  const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
      checkIfAuthed(store) ? (
        <Component {...props}/>
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/login'
        }}/>
      )
    )}/>
  )

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying out a few of the above suggestions, I found the best way to track the state of your store with updates is to use React-Redux's `useSelector` function which basically connects a functional component to the store.

```
import * as React from "react";
import {Redirect, Route, Switch} from "react-router";
import {Provider, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

// Your imports
import {IApplicationState,} from "./store/store";
import {Login} from "./routes/login/login.component";
import {getToken} from "./store/helpers/httpHelpers";


function handleRedirect() {
    if(!getToken()) {
        return <Redirect to="/login"/>;
    }
}

const restricted = (Component: _ComponentType, isLoggedIn: boolean) => {
   // Don't redirect here if there is a token in localStorage.
   // This is happening when we are on a restricted route and the user
   // refreshes & the isLoggedIn state hasn't been updated yet.
    return !isLoggedIn ? (
        () => handleRedirect()
    ) : () => <Route component={Component}/>
};

const AuthenticateRoutes = () => {
    const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state: IApplicationState) => state.auth.isLoggedIn);
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/downloads" render={restricted(Download, isLoggedIn)} />
        </Switch>
    );
};

export function App() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <>
                <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
                    <AuthenticateRoutes />
                </Router>
            </>
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

Comment: Please add the imports, especially in a TypeScript context.

Comment: @BairDev imports added, let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: yes, stupid question: what is `history`? It looks like an npm package.

Comment: @BairDev Explained here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/history