# Show progress bar BEFORE go to route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I'm developing a universal react application using redux. I use react-router v3.
I want to show a progress bar "BEFORE" going to next route (next route is fetching data from API).

for example imagine I am in "Home Page" and I want go to "Submit Page". when I click on the Submit Link (react-router Link) first show a progress bar **in "Home Page"** and wait for **Submit page data fetching** and **then** go to "Submit Page".
My React Routes:

```
<Route component={App}>
        <Route path={HomingRoutes.HomePage} component={HomePage}/>
        <Route path={HomingRoutes.SubmitPage} component={SubmitPage}/>
        <Route path={HomingRoutes.SearchPage} component={SearchPage}/>
        <Route path={`${HomingRoutes.DealsPage}`} component={DealsPage}/>
        <Route path={`${HomingRoutes.DealPage}/:id(/:title)`} component={DealPage}/>
        <Route path={`${HomingRoutes.Detail}/:id(/:title)`} component={DetailPage}/>
        <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
    </Route>
```

in Home Page :

```
<Link to "/Submit" >Submit</Link>
```

My Submit page Container code is :

```
class SubmitContainer extends React.Component {
    static readyOnActions(dispatch) {
        return Promise.all([
            dispatch(SubmitActions.fetchSubmitInitialData()),
        ]);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchSubmitInitialData();
    }
}
```

"**fetchSubmitInitialData**" is an action creator that fetch data from API.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `onEnter` hook https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback

Comment: @OrB how  can I dispatch my redux store from onEnter ?

Comment: You could import `store` directly, then use `store.dispatch()`. I like the approach described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35849970/accessing-redux-store-from-routes-set-up-via-react-router

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be to pass a `placeholder` component as props to your `SubmitPage` that will render only when data is fetching.

So you can use something like:

```
class SubmitContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true
    progress: 0,

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // fetch some data and update the state
    // consider updating the progress more often
    this.props.fetchSubmitInitialData()
      .then(() => {
         this.setState({ loading: false, progress: 100 })
      })
  }

  render() {
    const Placeholder = this.props.placeholder
    // Show the placeholder when loading
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <Placeholder loading progress={this.state.progress} />
    }

    // Otherwise render your component with the data
    return <SubmitPage data={/*..*/}>
  }
}
```

And finally pass you could use the component `HomePage` as placeholder like this:

```
<Route path={HomingRoutes.HomePage} component={HomePage}/>
<Route path={HomingRoutes.SubmitPage} render={(props) => (
         <SubmitContainer {...props} placeholder={HomePage} />
   )}/>
```

*Here I use the render props with React router v4. But I'm sure there is an equivalent for the version 3*

Now `HomePage` will render during data fetching and can use the props `loading` and `progress` to show a spinner or something

Answer (score 0):

You can add `onEnter` hook into your router and add `onEnter.js` inside your `SubmitContainer` folder and move `fetchSubmitInitialData` to  the `onEnter.js` then import your store here and dispatch it. the implementation might looks like this:

Your React-Route

```
import { onEnterSubmitPage } from './your onEnter path/onEnter'

<Route component={App}>
    <Route path={HomingRoutes.HomePage} component={HomePage}/>
    <Route path={HomingRoutes.SubmitPage} component={SubmitPage} onEnter={onEnterSubmitPage}/>
    <Route path={HomingRoutes.SearchPage} component={SearchPage}/>
    <Route path={`${HomingRoutes.DealsPage}`} component={DealsPage}/>
    <Route path={`${HomingRoutes.DealPage}/:id(/:title)`} component={DealPage}/>
    <Route path={`${HomingRoutes.Detail}/:id(/:title)`} component={DetailPage}/>
    <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
</Route>
```

create `onEnter.js` file in SubmitPage container:

```
/**
 *  Import dependencies and action creators
 */
import { store } from '../../index'
import { fetchSubmitInitialData } from './actions'

/**
 *  Define onEnter function
 */
 export function onEnterSubmitPage() {

   store.dispatch(fetchSubmitInitialData())
 }
```

then we can integrate state for progress bar into redux too.

`actions.js`

```
/** Import all dependencies here **/
import axios from 'axios'
import { FETCH_SUBMIT_INITIAL_DATA, IS_FETCHING_INITIAL_DATA } from './constants'

export function fetchSubmitInitialData() {
 /** this dispatch is from middleware **/ 
 return (dispatch) => {
     /** this will set progress bar to true **/
     dispatch(fetchSubmitInitialData(true))

     /** Your fetching action here, this will depend on your configuration **/
      axios.get(`url`, {{ headers: `bearer //your token`}})
         .then( (response) => {
            dispatch(fetchSubmitInitialData(false))
      })  
  }
 }

export function isFetchInitialData(status) {
 return {
  type: IS_FETCHING_INITIAL_DATA,
  status
 }
}
```

so there is no need to fetch the data inside SubmitPage container.

One solution would be to pass a placeholder component as props to your SubmitPage that will render only when data is fetching.

So you can use something like:

```
class SubmitContainer extends React.Component {

  render() {
   /** this come from your reducer **/
   const { isFetching, submitInitialData } = this.props
   // Show the placeholder when loading
   if (isFetching) {
     return <Loader />
   }

  // Otherwise render your component
  return <SubmitPage data={/*..*/}>
 }
}

// Map state to props
const mapStatetoProps = ({ app }) => {
     isFetching: //,
     submitInitialData: //
}

export default connect(mapStatetoProps, null)(SubmitContainer)
```